# One of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied

Tags: android, kotlin, text, android-jetpack-compose

I am iOS developer transferred to andriod development.
I faced a issue when I was creating a basic TextView()

```
@Composable
fun the_App(modifier: Modifier = Modifier
    .fillMaxSize()
    .wrapContentSize(Alignment.Center)
) {
    Column (
        modifier = modifier,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Text(text = R.string.text_test)
    }
}
```

There's red curve line on the Text() function.
And the a citation poped out:

```
None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied: 
public fun Text(text: AnnotatedString, modifier: Modifier = ..., color: Color = ..., fontSize: TextUnit = ..., fontStyle: FontStyle? = ..., fontWeight: FontWeight? = ..., fontFamily: FontFamily? = ..., letterSpacing: TextUnit = ..., textDecoration: TextDecoration? = ..., textAlign: TextAlign? = ..., lineHeight: TextUnit = ..., overflow: TextOverflow = ..., softWrap: Boolean = ..., maxLines: Int = ..., inlineContent: Map<String, InlineTextContent> = ..., onTextLayout: (TextLayoutResult) -> Unit = ..., style: TextStyle = ...): Unit defined in androidx.compose.material
public fun Text(text: String, modifier: Modifier = ..., color: Color = ..., fontSize: TextUnit = ..., fontStyle: FontStyle? = ..., fontWeight: FontWeight? = ..., fontFamily: FontFamily? = ..., letterSpacing: TextUnit = ..., textDecoration: TextDecoration? = ..., textAlign: TextAlign? = ..., lineHeight: TextUnit = ..., overflow: TextOverflow = ..., softWrap: Boolean = ..., maxLines: Int = ..., onTextLayout: (TextLayoutResult) -> Unit = ..., style: TextStyle = ...): Unit defined in androidx.compose.material
```

Answer (score 1):

### Problem

You are using string ressource id instead of a String or AnnotedString.

### Solution

In compose, you have a method called [stringResource(stringResId)](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/resources#strings) that allow you to get a string from a resources id.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun the_App(modifier: Modifier = Modifier
    .fillMaxSize()
    .wrapContentSize(Alignment.Center)
) {
    Column (
        modifier = modifier,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Text(text = stringResource(R.string.text_test))
    }
}
```