# None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied. text compose?

Tags: android, text, android-jetpack-compose

following text giving an error in my compose I did not understand what I am making wrong

```
Text(
                text = stringResource(R.string.meaning_word),
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(6.dp)
                    .align(alignment = Alignment.Start)
                    .fillMaxHeight(0.3f),
                colors = AppColors.mOffWhite,
                fontSize = 17.sp,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                lineHeight = 22.sp
            )
```

I am getting following error None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.

```
Text(AnnotatedString, Modifier = ..., Color = ..., TextUnit = ..., FontStyle? = ..., FontWeight? = ..., FontFamily? = ..., TextUnit = ..., TextDecoration? = ..., TextAlign? = ..., TextUnit = ..., TextOverflow = ..., Boolean = ..., Int = ..., Map<String, InlineTextContent> = ..., (TextLayoutResult) → Unit = ..., TextStyle = ...) defined in androidx.compose.material
Text(String, Modifier = ..., Color = ..., TextUnit = ..., FontStyle? = ..., FontWeight? = ..., FontFamily? = ..., TextUnit = ..., TextDecoration? = ..., TextAlign? = ..., TextUnit = ..., TextOverflow = ..., Boolean = ..., Int = ..., (TextLayoutResult) → Unit = ..., TextStyle = ...) defined in androidx.compose.material
```

I have tried following answer [One of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73997891/one-of-the-following-functions-can-be-called-with-the-arguments-supplied) did not help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because there is no Text function with `colors` param. It's color also you need to change Alignment.Start which is Alignment.Horizontal to one of

[image]